# What is the next colour?

Tags: pattern

[image]

What would be the next colour in the sequence.

The correct answer will also state the logic behind it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the next image in the sequence:

[image: Next image]

Look at the hex colours for each image - each pair increments on a different scale.

Pair 1: 3C 4E 60 72 ... 84 (+18)
Pair 2: 55 5C 63 6A ... 71 (+7)
Pair 3: 64 66 68 6A ... 6C (+2)

The increments have been chosen because

> Letter 18 is R, letter 7 is G and letter 2 is B - RGB is the ugly twin sister of HEX colors (ugly twin sister in CSS, anyway :P)

For giggles, you could also argue that there's a 4th pair:

> Pair 4: 1, 1, 1 ... 1 (RGBA is RGB with Alpha, ie. opacity)

Comment: hmm.. not bad... any ReasoninG Behind the increment amounts?

Comment: @G.Rassovsky yes, that's the gap between each one in the sequence :P If you want me to tell you why you chose those specific increments, no, I'm not sure right now :-)

Comment: look into my comment above more carefully - when you find out add it to your answer :D

Comment: @G.Rassovsky Oh I see. Edited that in :-)

Comment: I believe you meant RGB, not RBG.